# FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not installed when working in a catalog "resources"

Tags: java

My project uses bat file in resources (tracert parser project):

```
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("trace.bat");
            File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            scan = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("cmd /c " + absolutePath + " " + ip);
```

Далее я работаю с

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = (new InputStreamReader(scan.getInputStream()));
```

Everything works fine in the IDE. After building in app-image I get an error:

```
2023-07-28 10:07:22,157 ERROR r.f.s.WorkerConnection [Thread-9] ERROR: 
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not installed
    at java.nio.file.Path.of(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ru.fezas.scanet.WorkerConnection.runSystemCommand(WorkerConnection.java:130) [scanet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at ru.fezas.scanet.WorkerConnection.run(WorkerConnection.java:166) [scanet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
```

bat file content

```
@echo off
chcp.com 65001
tracert -w 1 %1
```

Comment: The `trace.bat` file is inside the JAR file for your application. You’ll need to write it onto the file system to use it in this way.

Comment: Print the value of the [URL] `res`, i.e. `System.out.println(res);` and you will see the problem. In any case you probably don't need to run the batch file. You can probably use class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)